# Does Tkinter hang on constantly changing the image?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm designing a GUI with Tkinter. It has many frames(pages) that by pressing a button in one frame, that frame is hided and next frame is displayed. Each of the button in each frames(pages) has variable images, so I need a function that changes the button image of each frames(pages) being displayed.

I have written the following code and it is working. (Because the number of my frames was high, here I put only the code containing two frames)
According to my design, when we reach the last frame, we automatically return to the first frame after a few seconds.
The problem is that when the system returns to the first frame, the images are no longer changed and the system is disrupted.

At first, I thought it was a hardware problem. So I upgraded my hardware to Raspberry Pi 4 with RAM 4. But then I noticed that even when the system crashes, only 25% of RAM and CPU involved. Therefore, it was not a problem. (I also prepared a fan to reduce its temperature & I bought the fastest microSD for fast data transfer from microSD)

where is the problem from?
The only thing I can think of is that the system hangs because I put the image change function in the main function. But I don't know how to separate the two?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Project(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)      
        
        self.counter = 1
        self.animation_direction = 1  # it will add `+1` to self.counter

        self.sw = 1000
        self.sh = 1800
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.configure(background="#000000")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.container = container
        
        self.frames = {}
        
        for F in ( PageStart, PageOne):   
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            
        self.show_frame(PageStart)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.cont = cont

        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
          
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.configure(background="#000000")      
        frame.grid()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.sw,self.sh,0,0))
        
        #frame.counter()

        self.change_image()
        
    def twoside(self, inputaddress, startframe, stopframe):
        self.input = inputaddress
        self.startframe = startframe
        self.stopframe = stopframe       
        
        self.counter += self.animation_direction

        self.address = '%s%s.jpg' % (self.input, self.counter)
        
        if self.counter == self.stopframe:
            self.animation_direction = -self.animation_direction
        if self.counter == self.startframe:
            self.animation_direction = -self.animation_direction
           
    def get_address(self):
        return self.address  
           
    def change_image(self):
        if self.cont == PageStart:
            self.frames[self.cont].counter()
            self.after(100, self.change_image)
        
           
class PageStart(tk.Frame):  # PEP8: UpperCaseNames for classes
        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.ButtonStyle = ttk.Style()
        self.ButtonStyle.configure("Tabedstart.TButton", background="#000000", borderwidth=0)
        self.ButtonStyle.map("Tabedstart.TButton", background=[('selected', "#000000")])
        
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, style="Tabedstart.TButton", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        self.button.pack(pady=320)     
        
        self.counter()      
        
    def counter(self):
      
        self.inputaddress = "/home/pi/Documents/Reference0/"
        self.controller.twoside(self.inputaddress, 0, 138)
        
        self.address = self.controller.get_address()  # PEP8: lower_case_names for functions/methods and variables
        self.photo = Image.open(self.address)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo)
        
        self.button.image = self.photo
        self.button.config(image=self.photo)
        

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.ButtonStyle = ttk.Style()
        self.ButtonStyle.configure("Tabedstart.TButton", background="#000000", borderwidth=0)
        self.ButtonStyle.map("Tabedstart.TButton", background=[('selected', "#000000")])
        
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, style="Tabedstart.TButton", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageStart))
        self.button.pack(pady=320)
        
        self.counter()      
        
    def counter(self):
      
        self.inputaddress = "/home/pi/Documents/Reference1/"
        self.controller.twoside(self.inputaddress, 0, 138)
        
        self.address = self.controller.get_address()
        self.photo = Image.open(self.address)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo)
        
        self.button.image = self.photo
        self.button.config(image=self.photo)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Project()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you start, `self.counter` is 1 - so you begin by displaying an image with `1` in the filename.  But when you reach the end and start decrementing the counter, you go down to 0 - does an image with `0` in the filename actually exist?  What exactly do you mean by "the system is disrupted", anyway?

Comment: yes, I have an image with 0 in the filename.
The system disrupts after working for a while (generally when we reach the end of all frames and go back to the first frame), which means that the get_address function works and creates a new address, but no photo are loaded and displayed.

Comment: I'm guessing that the image change function should be separated from the main function and run in a separate thread, but my efforts have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong using pc. Actually, I haven't attempt on Raspberry Pi. I will inform later.

Comment: It works on Raspberry Pi.